# Does function-level linking in VC++ have any negative effects?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

Visual C++ has [function-level linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa71f43(VS.80).aspx). Looks like it's a great thing - it can reduce the size of generated executables.

Does it have any negative effects? Will I have to pay anything for the advantages of this option or can I just turn it on and enjoy the benefits?

Comment: The link in the question seems to be changed and leads to some different page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there could be some small increase of compilation time. I don't think that it can affect negativily anything else.

Comment: Correct, especially in combination with /OPT:REF. The linker will need to consider for each function whether it's used. That's not free.